# Unable to install Phpmyadmin on centos 7 with php update to 7

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have php 7 updated but after update i am unable to install phpmyadmin i am getting below error

```
  Processing Conflict: php70u-common-7.0.11-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: *Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64* is pretty self explanatory...

Comment: you have to remove php 5.4.16, then install php 7